# Three.js - How to merge multiple GLTF models into one?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know there is the grouping method:

```
...

//after loading cube models
const group = new THREE.Group();
group.add( cube1 );
group.add( cube2 );
group.add( cube3 );

scene.add( group ); //This gives me 3 calls when rendering
```

but this doesn't affect performance, it's just to make things synthetically more clear.

I would like to merge `cube1`, `cube2`, & `cube3` into a single object to reduce the number of calls in the scene

```
import { BufferGeometryUtils } from '../jsm/BufferGeometryUtils.js'; //gives error: BufferGeometryUtils.js doesn't export BufferGeometryUtils

var geometries = [];

geometries.push( cube1 );
geometries.push( cube2 );
geometries.push( cube3 );

const cubes = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries( geometries );//doesn't work (outdated?)

scene.add( cubes );
```

I've followed some tutorials on `BufferGeometryUtils`, but they seem outdated since `BufferGeometryUtils.js` doesn't export a `BufferGeometryUtils` constructor

Comment: Try: `import * as BufferGeometryUtils from '../jsm/BufferGeometryUtils.js';`

Comment: @prisoner849 it's now giving me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object -- BufferGeometryUtils.js:30`

Comment: Only you know what `cube1`, `cube2` and `cube3` are. Object3D, Mesh, BufferGeometry or something else. Better to provide a working live code example or a code snippet, that demonstrates the issue. Otherwise, it's just random shots in attempt to choose what's wrong.